# Rails has_many through - query through the relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Running rails 6.0.3.2 / ruby 2.7.1

I have a has_many through-relationship that isn't behaving as expected.

My models look like this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
       has_many :item_permissions
       has_many :users, :through => :item_permissions
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :item_permissions
      has_many :items, :through => :item_permissions
end

class ItemPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :items
    belongs_to :users
end
```

Now I want to retrieve all Items that a certain User has permission to:

```
u = User.find(1)

u.items
```

gives me an error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant User::Items)
```

I can get the permission entries with

```
u.item_permissions
```

Is there any way to retrieve the items for a certain user or also the other way round receiving all users that are linked to a specific item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in your `belongs_to` declarations, in both your are using the plural word instead of the singular one to reference the associated model. Try with:

```
class ItemPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :item # :item instead of :items
    belongs_to :user # :user instead of :users
end
```

More information [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).